# Задача на сортировку «Носки»

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, сортировка, список

Только начал изучать Python. Помогите, пожалуйста, с задачей.

**Условие:**
Имеется стол длины . На столе разложено  носков так, что никакой носок не вылезает за границы стола. Далее имеется умный мальчик Вася, который хочет (сугубо в корыстных целях) замерить толщину покрытия стола носками в  точках. Конец носка также накрывает точку стола, в которой он находится.

**Входные данные:**
В первой строке заданы , ,  (`1 ≤  ≤ 10000`, `1 ≤  ≤ 10000`, `1 ≤  ≤ 100000`). Далее идут  пар чисел  `≤`  от `1` до  — левые и правые концы носков, каждая в отдельной строке. Затем идут  чисел от `1` до  — интересующие Васю точки, каждое в отдельной строке. Все числа целые.

**Выходные данные:**
Выведите  чисел — толщину носкового покрытия в каждой точке.

Я понял, как решить задачу. Написал код:

```
l,n,m = map(int, input().split())
socks = [[int(j) for j in input().split()] for i in range(n)]
checkPoints = []
for i in range(m):
    checkPoints.append(int(input()))

C = [0 for j in range(l+1)]

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(socks[i][0], socks[i][1]+1):
        C[j] += 1

for i in m:
    print(C[i])
```

На двух последних строчках возникает ошибка `TypeError: ‘int’ object is not iterable`. Немного не понимаю, как можно исправить её. Помогите, пожалуста.

Comment: В строке `socks = [[int(j) for j in input().split()]` вы читаете все оставшиеся строки. И те, что содержат носки, и те, где задаются контрольные точки. Вам нужно прочитать n строк.

Comment: А Вы что, поиcк по сайту вообще не используете?

Comment: @MBo, Перед задаванием собственного вопроса, я всегда изучаю вопросы по схожим темам. Просто мне было непонятно Ваше и чужие решения, а для комментария не хватало репутации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Два варианта на выбор

## Первый - красивый

Красиво можно решить вот так.

Создайте два массива `L` и `R`. В массиве `L` хранятся пары `(l, n)`, где l - координата левого конца `n`-ного носка. В массиве `R` пары `(r,n)` - координата правого конца `n`-го носка. Оба массива отсортированы по возрастанию координаты.

Чтобы вычислить покрытие для точки с координатой `x`, находите все пары `(l,n)` из `L`, для которых `l<=x`, и все `(r,n')`, для которых `x<=r`. Общие номера `n` и `n'` - читай, пересечение множеств, - это номера тех носков, которые покрывают точку x.

Оценка сложности поиска общих номеров. Списки чисел `n` и `n'` нужно отсортировать - оценка `2N ln(N)`, потом найти в этих списках общие элементы - сложность порядка `2N`, то есть суммарная сложность для `M` точек `2MN(ln(N)+1)`

## Второй - быстрый

с предварительной обработкой массива носков.

задача решается так: создаётся массив `C` целых чисел длиной `L+1`. Этот массив будет хранить покрытие для каждой точки. Вначале в каждом элементе массива значение `0` - нет ни одного носка, покрытие везде `0`.

При добавлении очередного носка c координатами `[l,r]` инкрементируем `C[i]` для всех индексов от `l` до `r`

После того, как добавлены N носков, в массиве C толщина покрытия для каждой точки.

Если `sock_len` - средняя длина носка, то сложность алгоритма `N sock_len` по времени. От числа точек `M` вообще не зависит.

Если средняя длина носков невелика, `sock_len < 2M(ln(N) + 1)`, то второй вариант быстрее первого. *На самом деле это не совсем так, `2M(ln(N) + 1)` - это верхняя граница, и фактическая сложность может быть гораздо меньше, но мне сейчас лень считать точнее*

Это общее правило - тратим память для большей скорости.

Запрограммировать сможете?

Comment: @daniil_simonov, обратите внимание, что второе решение не на сортировку.

Comment: @Pak_Uula, да, но я доделал второе решение, отправил на проверку, всё правильно — решение прошло проверку. Большое Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

**Сверхскоростное решение**

Решение можно придумать за O(L). Просто вместо прохода по всему массиву каждый раз при добавлении отрезка, мы будем добавлять в массив только начало и конец. (Полуинтервалом [) ). Если начало, то прибавляем единицу a[l] += 1, а если конец, то вычитаем ее a[r + 1] -= 1. Потом проходимся по этому массиву, и определяем уровень вложенности в любой точке. Решение без сортировки.

```
l, n, m = map(int, input().split())

deltaArr = [0] * l
#Создаем массив изменений длинной l. Он нам поможет определить
#уровень вложенности в любой точке
#Если носок начался, уровень вложенности в i точке увеличился
#Если носок закончился, то уровень вложенности уменьшился
for i in range(n):
    left, right = map(int, input().split())
    left -= 1
    right -= 1
    deltaArr[left] += 1
    #добавляем носок полуинтервалом, т.к конец носка тоже должен учитываться
    #Мы можем выйти за границы массива, обязательно проверяем это
    if (right + 1 < l):
        deltaArr[right + 1] -= 1

#Создаем массив, i элемент которого будет содержать информацию о вложенности в i точке  
socks = [0] * l 

value = 0

for i in range (l):
    value += deltaArr[i]
    socks[i] = value

for i in range(m):
    point = int(input())
    print(socks[point - 1])
```

**Тестируем...**

```
31 12 4
19 20
1 3
9 26
8 31
15 26
15 20
5 20
17 27
21 23
2 24
10 19
1 27
15
23
28
23
```

**Ответ:**

```
8
7
1
7
```

Почему мы добавляем носок(отрезок) полуинтервалом? Потому что, правый конец носка, как и левый, тоже является его частью и закончится он тогда, когда закончится правый носок и начнется стол/другой носок

Comment: Попробовал сделать в точности по-предложенному алгоритму - не получилось. По условию задачи крайние точки тоже должны считаться, а если делать `+1/-1`, то когда точка попадает на конец носка, этот носок не учитывается. Пример: есть три носка  -`2 7`, `3 7`, `4 7`, требуется определить толщину в точке `7`. Соответственно имеем три `1` в точках `2`, `3`, `4` и `-3` в точке `7`. При сложении этих значенией получаем ноль вместо **3-х** - концы с началами взаимно сократились. Тоже самое, если один носок заканчивается в точке `7` (-1), а другой начинается в точке `7` (+1) - имеем `0` вместо `2`.

Comment: Я нашёл выход - создаю два списка, в один добавляю только начала носков (`+1`), в другой только концы (`-1`) и для ответа складываю их, исключив из списка с концами последний элемент. Это позволяет учитывать носки с концами в требуемой точке.

Comment: Конечно, выше решение тоже имеет право на существование. Но я написал полуинтервал, то есть, если отрезок 1 - 3, мы добавляем единицу в a[0], а вычитаем из a[3]. Главное проверить, что не вышли за границы массива

Comment: Добавьте к отрезку `1 3` отрезок `3 5` и получите **0** вместо **2** в `a[3]`. Потому что при добавлении первого отрезка в `a[3]` идёт `-1`, а при добавлении второго `+1`. Итого: по факту у нас два отрезка в точке `3`, один заканчивается, другой начинается, а в `a[3]` лежит **0**.

Comment: Чел. При добавление отрезка 1, 3 в a[1] = 1, a[4] = -1. При добавление отрезка 3, 5, в a[3] = 1, в а[6] = -1. (Это псеадокот, допустим, индексация с единицы).

Comment: При проходе по массиву, когда доходим до точки 3, уже получаем ответ два. Возможно, ты не до конца понял, что я делаю

Comment: Не понимаю. Почему концы отрезков пишутся со смещением: 3-ка из отрезка `1 3` в `a[4]`, 5-ка из отрезка `3 5` в `a[6]`? А если три отрезка: `1 3`, `4 6`, `3 5`? Было бы хорошо, если бы вы реализовали свой алгоритм и добавили в ответ, стало бы понятнее, о чём идёт речь.

Comment: Потому что при проходе по массиву, если отрезок 1 3, он начнется  в точке один, но кончится только в точке 4.(Концы отпезков тоже должны учитываться, в качестве слоя). Я попробую переписать свою реализацию алгоритма с с++ на пайтон и добавить в решение

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Действительно, можно ведь просто "закрывать" носок на ячейку позже, тогда концы не сокращаются с началами следующих носков и все носки в требуемой точке учитываются - второй список не нужен. Подправил своё решение.

Answer (score 2):

#### Вариант № 1, с использованием сортировки

**Идея**

1. Требуется узнать, сколько носков приходится на искомую точку `M`. Подходящим считается носок, начало которого <= `M`, конец которого >= `M`, другими словами, если заменить носок на отрезок, то точка `M` должна входить в этот отрезок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Самый простой и медленный способ это перебрать все носки. Его можно усовершенствовать, отсортировав начала носков по возрастанию. Тогда перебор можно закончить, когда пошли отрезки (носки), которые начинаются после точки `M`. Тоже самое с концами носков - нет смысла проверять отрезки, заканчивающиеся раньше точки `M`. Тут поможет вторая сортировка - расположить концы по убыванию - как только пошли концы меньше точки `M`, проверку можно заканчивать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Решение**

```
def thickness_at_point(point, socks):
    cnt = 0
    # socks - отсортированный список.
    # Благодаря его отсортированности, можно завершать работу
    # как только пошли "начала" носков, превышающие требуемую точку
    for sock_start, sock_ends in socks:
        if point < sock_start:
            return cnt
        # Списки с концами тоже отсортированны, поэтому можно
        # завершать проверку при первом неподходящем значении, так как
        # известно, что остальные концы меньше или равны текущему,
        # соответствено также не подходят.
        for sock_end in sock_ends:
            if point > sock_end:
                break
            cnt += 1

    return cnt

desk_len, socks_num, points_num = map(int, input().split())

# Словарь нужен для оптимизации - складываем под одним ключом все носки с
# одинаковым началом. Концы этих носков добавляем в список, который хранится
# в значении данного ключа.
dct = {}
for _ in range(socks_num):
    start, end = map(int, input().split())
    dct.setdefault(start, [])
    dct[start].append(end)

# Переводим словарь в список содержащий кортеж вида: 
# (точка начала носка, [концы всех носков, стартующих с этого начала])
# Например, (5, [15, 10, 8, 7]) означает, что есть 4 носка,
# начинающихся в точке 5 и заканчивающихся в точках 15, 10, 8, 7.
# Список с концами должен быть отсортирован в обратном порядке
socks_lst = []
for start, ends in dct.items():
    socks_lst.append( (start, sorted(ends, reverse=True)))

# Сортируем список по "началам носков".
socks_lst.sort()

points_lst = [int(input()) for _ in range(points_num)]

for point in points_lst:
    print(thickness_at_point(point, socks_lst))
```

---

#### Вариант № 2, короткий и быстрый, но без использования сортировки

Идея взята из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134035/325224).

```
desk_len, socks_num, points_num = map(int, input().split())

socks_lst = [0] * (desk_len + 2)

for _ in range(socks_num):
    start, end = map(int, input().split())
    socks_lst[start] += 1
    socks_lst[end + 1] -= 1

points_lst = [int(input()) for _ in range(points_num)]

for point in points_lst:
    print(sum(socks_lst[:point + 1]))
```

#### Тестирование обоих вариантов

**Input**

```
39 4 7 
3 21
3 15
3 17
2 20
4
17
33
5
9
25
37
```

**Output**

```
4
3
0
4
4
0
0
```